# How To Get Order_ID From Webhook Response - Shopify & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I have registered my webhooks in my shopify app and i am able to receive responses from the webhook to my specified address.

But what i want to do now is, when i create an order and the response is sent to the specified address, how can i `get the ID of the order created` ?

I want to include the `order id` in the notification sent to the customer?

PS: I am new to laravel and creating apps in shopify.

**Controller**

```
  public function orderCreateWebhook(Request $request)
    {              
        //get order_id here and send notification
        notification = "A new order with id [order_id] has been 
                       created";
        SendSMS(notification); 
    }

   public function registerOrderCreateWebhook(Request $request)
    {
            $shop = "example.myshopify.com";
            $token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            $shopify = Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token);
            Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token)->post("admin/webhooks.json", ['webhook' => 
             ['topic' => 'orders/create',
             'address' => 'https://shop.domain.com/order-create-webhook',
             'format' => 'json'
             ]
            ]);
    }
```

**Web**

```
//register order create
Route::get('/register-order-create-webhook', 'AppController@registerOrderCreateWebhook');  
Route::post('order-create-webhook', 'AppController@orderCreateWebhook');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get the content of request body    
$order = $request->getContent();

// decode json and covert to array
$order = json_decode($order, true);

// get the 'id' key which is your order id    
$order_id = $order['id'];
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain about it

Comment: Yeah just added comments :)